# How to install htop on OS X using Homebrew?

Tags: macos, homebrew, htop

I am trying install htop using brew:

```
➜  ~  brew install htop
Error: You must `brew link autoconf' before htop-osx can be installed
```

Then I am doing

```
brew link autoconf
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69... Warning: Could not link autoconf. Unlinking...
Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69/share/emacs/site-lisp/autotest-mode.elc
Target /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/autotest-mode.elc already exists. You may need to delete it. 
To force the link and overwrite all other conflicting files, do:
brew link --overwrite formula_name
To list all files that would be deleted:
brew link --overwrite --dry-run formula_name
```

What is root of the problem?

Comment: Did you install `emacs` through Homebrew already? If so, you can probably just overwrite it.

Comment: emacs installed using other binaries, should I remove it and istall emacs using brew?

Comment: Yeah, I'd remove the other one and reinstall the brew version if you don't need it to be the exact same version—it can be that they're a little different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just ran into this issue myself!

**Open your terminal, trying installing:**

```
brew install htop
```

**Output:**

> $ brew install htop Warning: It appears you have MacPorts or Fink
>   installed. Software installed with other package managers causes known
>   problems for Homebrew. If a formula fails to build, uninstall
>   MacPorts/Fink and try again. Error: You must `brew link autoconf'
>   before htop-osx can be installed

**Now, fix:**

```
sudo brew link autoconf
```

Let me know if this helps!

After, it might ask you to link "htop":

```
sudo brew link htop
```

Basically, all the "linkking" problems need root to create the correct symlinks in order to work properly on your system.

Regards,

Comment: brew refused to do this: Error: Cowardly refusing to 'sudo brew link'
You can use brew with sudo, but only if the brew executable is owned by root.
However, this is both not recommended and completely unsupported so do so at
your own risk.